# Value-Of select multiple elements

Tags: html, xslt

/*
Edited 
*/

I have a 3 column table like this with text insert in the first, 3 editable divs, in the second and two editable divs with text as shown below and i would like if when i call my template,that i have to call twice to get the template as it is but with the codes change to the one wit _1 on the end and with _2 on the end...

```
     <xsl:call-template name="my_template">
      <xsl:with-param name="code" select="'code_1'"/>
     </xsl:call-template>

     <xsl:call-template name="my_template">
      <xsl:with-param name="code" select="'code_2'"/>
     </xsl:call-template>


<table>
<tr>
<xsl:for each select="node/contains(@someCode,'my_value_code_for both_in_this_to_show_text_below_and_divs_')">
<td>
Text1
Text2
Text3
</td>
<td>
<DIV>
  <DIV id="webedit" formid="{$id}"  max_word_count="{$max_word_count}" comment="Title" width="770" style="background-color:#fff; margin-bottom:3pt;">
            <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="//node[@clientCode='my_div_code']"/>
           </DIV>
  <DIV id="webedit" formid="{$id}"  max_word_count="{$max_word_count}" comment="Title" width="770" style="background-color:#fff; margin-bottom:3pt;">
            <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="//node[@clientCode='my_div_code']"/>
           </DIV>
  <DIV id="webedit" formid="{$id}"  max_word_count="{$max_word_count}" comment="Title" width="770" style="background-color:#fff; margin-bottom:3pt;">
            <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="//node[@clientCode='my_div_code']"/>
           </DIV>
</DIV>
</td>
<td>
<div width="100%">Text1:</DIV>
  <DIV id="webedit" formid="{$id}"  max_word_count="{$max_word_count}" comment="Title" width="770" style="background-color:#fff; margin-bottom:3pt;">
            <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="//node[@clientCode='my_div_code']"/>
           </DIV>
<div width="100%">Text1:</DIV>
  <DIV id="webedit" formid="{$id}"  max_word_count="{$max_word_count}" comment="Title" width="770" style="background-color:#fff; margin-bottom:3pt;">
            <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="//node[@clientCode='my_div_code']"/>
           </DIV>
</td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
```

Hope you did understand my code and question,if not i'll update it even more.
Thanks again.

Comment: The answer is probably 'yes' but it would help if you could show a sample of you current input XML and the output you would expect. Thanks!

Comment: I think you are confused. The cpntext of the for-each would be the nodes matched. The value-of should take this into account